# Restrictions on the rules of a game theory model

Tags: game-theory

I am to model a problem and I want to employ game theory. The players are network's agents  P = $\{1,\cdots,N\}$, the strategies S = $\{Red,Green\}$.

The rules are:

- at the beginning of the game, each player selects a strategy.
- the agents who selected Red can not do any further action in the game.
- the agents who selected green will remain green unless they are *Unstable*: They have more Red neighbors than green. In this case they convert their strategy to Red, and the game continues until no further action is possible (I.e., all green nodes are surrounded by sufficient number of green nodes)

Is this game theoretic model valid from game theory perspective? is there any restriction on the rules of a game that should be followed?

Comment: When you say the game continues, do you mean that players who are currently playing green have the option to switch to red? So, in the first round, players choose red or green. Then, in each subsequent round, players who enter the round green are allowed to switch to red, which may lead to others being forced to?

Comment: That is true, green players have the option to turn Red in the subsequent rounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model makes sense as a game, except that it misses one thing: utility functions. For game-theoretic reasoning to make sense, you have to have some sort of function for each player, which describes the utility incurred, for example after each step of the game, or at the end of the game.

In either case, if you add a utility function, it sounds like your game could easily be modeled as a stochastic game (you actually don't even need the stochastic part, your transitions would be deterministic). You could also model it as an extensive-form game, but I think that'd be less useful, unless there are some components to the problem that I am unaware of.

Comment: The utility is the number of $Green - Red$ neighbors. And this is what made me to ask the question, as the number of the green neighbors cannot increased, unlike the number of red neighbors, according to the game rules.

Comment: In that case, the game seems trivial. If each player's utility is just #Green - #Red neighbors, then every player choosing green is a weakly dominant strategy. From your description above, I don't see why anyone would ever choose red?

Comment: Let us say that the strategy selection, including Red, is a stochastic process. That is, each player is assigned to either red or green randomly at the beginning of the game. This leaves red players without any possible moves in the further rounds.

Comment: I still think this has the same problem. Any green player will want to remain green. If a player switches to read, it does not affect her own utility directly, but it can only lead to neighbors potentially switching to red, never to them switching to green. For this to make sense game-theoretically, there needs to be some strategic nuance to this choice, right now it doesn't really seem like a game. A weakly optimal strategy here is still "stay green as long as possible."

Comment: Indeed - currently it's just a stochastic process with no strategic nuance. I should say though that games on networks is a pretty new and exciting literature in economics. One entry point is Jackson and Zenou 2014 (http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2136179).